# error 503 with gwt project

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to run a GWT project into DevMode, After running google compilation and lanching the devMode i'm getting a url, so when running into mozila, i'm getting the 503 error.
my console is displaying the following :

`[ERROR] 503 - GET /travelApp?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:49822 (127.0.0.1) 1296 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: localhost:8888
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
      Connection: keep-alive
   Response headers
      Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
      Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
      Content-Length: 1296`

i don't understand the problem, can you help me with that ?

Comment: There must be error logs about why the webapp couldn't start.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the response from the webserver. The Error-Code is 503 - Service Unavailable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Most likey, your application failed to start.

Do you have any logs? There might be any usefull stacktraces.

Do you use the build-in Jetty? I found out, that it's sometimes hard to get log entries from it. Maybe you can try to deploy the application to tomcat to get a more helpful errorlog.